# Opening an app in seconds after the button is pressed in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having trouble with my program. If I pressed the button, the timer will be activated. After a few seconds, the app should open. But it doesn't work. How can I make it work? Sorry for my English. I'm from Indonesia.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import time

root = Tk()
my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)
root.title("Tkinter window")
root.geometry("400x400")

def startapp():
    t = 3
    if time.sleep(t):
        os.startfile("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe")

StartButton=Button(root, text='Start', command=startapp)
StartButton.pack()    

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `time.sleep()` doesn't return anything, so that `if` will never execute.  Note that `time.sleep()` is not something you want to be using in a GUI program anyway, as it locks up the user interface for the duration.  In Tkinter, `root.after()` is generally what you want to use instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Very simple answer!!!**

```
def startapp():
    t = 3.0
    time.sleep(t)
    os.startfile("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe")
```

time.sleep() is a function that adding delay! So you don't have to check it using another if condition...